# Caramels without cream or condensed milk?

Tags: candy

I have a chocolate caramel recipe that I love, but I'd like to tweak it to not use heavy cream, which I don't keep for anything else. However, I always have butter. Any thoughts on how I would need to adjust the ingredients, to not need heavy cream? Here's what I have now:

3 tablespoons cocoa powder

1/2 cup sugar

1/4 cup plus 1/8 cup light corn syrup

1 tablespoon oil

3/4 cup heavy whipping cream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use butter easily, there are good caramels based on butter.

As a starting point in reengineering the recipe, I would try 1/3 of the cream amount as butter (by weight). So 3/4 * 240 g (1 cup of cream, rounded) / 3 = 60 g butter. Cream has about 33% milk fat, and the water in it evaporates anyway when making the caramels. You'll obviously have to test it and tweak it until you have arrived at the best substitution ratio. Removing the oil may simplify things, it's unlikely to have much contribution when you are working with butter.

Comment: Thanks for this. I looked up a lot of "butter caramel" recipes, but all of them that I saw use either heavy cream or condensed milk as well as butter. I will attempt to substitute the butter for the cream correctly.
FYI - I had the oil in there because the original recipe called for bakers chocolate, and a substitute for that was cocoa, and oil. You're right, I should just add a little bit more butter and drop the oil to simplify.

Comment: FYI - I altered the recipe like below. It worked great, and a good side effect is that it cooked up MUCH faster - probably because there wasn't so much water to cook off, from the cream.

3 tablespoons cocoa powder
1/2 cup sugar
1/4 cup plus 1/8 cup light corn syrup 
1/2 cup MINUS 1 tablespoon butter

Answer (score 0):

If it just a matter of having it on hand, you could use heavy cream powder.

[example from amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OCV3QRW)

The labels say this stuff is good for 2 years.  I have never used cream powder but have definitely used milk powder and buttermilk powder, which have longer shelf lives so they stay available for intermittent use.

Now that I live with someone who likes cream in her coffee maybe I will pick up some of this cream powder and see what is what.